# What would be the integration uri for aws apigateway swagger file for query params?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, http, swagger, aws-api-gateway

```
    "paths": {
        "/{x}/{y}": {
          "put": {
    x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
              "uri": "https://hostname/contextpath/{x}/{y}"
 "httpMethod": "PUT",
          "type": "http"
    }
    }
    }
```

If I do have query params for that resource then my invoke url would be  https://apiid.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/x/y?queryparam1=value1&queryparam2=value2&queryparam3=value3&queryparam4=value4.
what would be my uri type in the integration request for my http backend?
How do I pass query params when calling it https://hostname/contextpath/{x}/{y}?**=**&**=** ? Can anyone suggest me how to pass query params when integrating with http type?